# Error message "Failed to enable dataprep" when allowing Trifacta to access project data

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

i connected several projects... but this one gives an error. Can anyone help?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E407S.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to an internal project/billing configuration. Since this kind of messages can be thrown when the accounts have payment issues, I think that you should firstly [verify that your billing account is in a good status](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-linked); however, if you continue getting this error message after this validation, I suggest you to take a look the **Issue Tracker** tool that you can use to raise a [Dataprep ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190822&template=1100238) in order to verify this scenario with the Google Technical Support Team.

Comment: Thnx, i raised a ticket